# convert endnote XML to an R dataframe

Tags: r, xml

I'm hoping to convert xml output from Endnote into an R dataframe, with each child node a separate column.

A similar question has previously been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719400/how-to-get-endnote-xml-file-into-an-r-data-frame), but the answer did not resolve the issue of records with multiple authors, keywords etc. (although the problem was noted).

I am wondering how I might include a separator (e.g. ;) for fields such as contributors, periodical, keywords, which often return multiple values.

Example data is below. As can be seen, the entries for for the fields noted above have multiple entries that have been appended with no separator.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

urldata<-"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nickbond/4f5a600836bf43a60d99e2a63e5a62de/raw/2088f8065eebbfe9e57c761ffa801b0a18588498/endnote.xml"
endnotexml<-xmlParse(getURL(urldata))
xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(endnotexml,'//*/record'))
```

I have tried a range of approaches - including trying to first convert to a list, and iterating over entries via a for-loop. The later was way too slow for the number of cases I have. Any assistance very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML has too many levels for `xmlToDataFrame` to work well, so I would create a function that combines multiple tags into a delimited list (and also add NAs for missing nodes)

```
x <-  getNodeSet(endnotexml,'//record')

xpath2 <-function(x, ...){
    y <- xpathSApply(x, ...)
    y <- gsub(",", "", y)  # remove commas if using comma separator
    ifelse(length(y) == 0, NA,  paste(y, collapse=", "))
}
```

Use the leading `.` so the xpath is relative to that node and get the columns you need.  Note `xmlGetAttr` will also work.

```
res <- data.frame(
  authors = sapply(x, xpath2, ".//author", xmlValue),
   year   = sapply(x, xpath2, ".//dates/year", xmlValue),
  journal = sapply(x, xpath2, ".//periodical/full-title", xmlValue),
 ref_type = sapply(x, xpath2, ".//ref-type", xmlGetAttr, "name")
 )

 res
                                       authors year                journal        ref_type
 1                     Abbott I., Le Maitre D. 2010        Austral Ecology Journal Article
 2           Abbott S., Chadwick D., Street G. 2007 Exploration Geophysics Journal Article
 3 Abdel-Fattah Z. A., Kora M. A., Ayyad S. N. 2013                 Facies Journal article
```

Comment: Thanks very much Chris. This works just as described and it is an easy process to add additional nodes/columns as needed. Many thanks!!